# Unable to authenticate Asp.net WebApi using OAuth and twitter external provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, twitter

I have created `Asp.net WebApi` and enable `TwitterAuthentication` code.

On `HomeController.cs` used `[Authorize]` attribute.

Now how can I verify credentials and give access to Authorize Controller without open login box ?

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
                consumerKey: "mykey",
                consumerSecret: "mysecret");
        }
```

> I have added one application into twitter app - get the consumer key.
> and consumer secret.
>
> I do not want a twitter login popup to be opened
> for login credentials while authorizing webapi.